# Subtract background in WebRTC

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc

I am looking for capture a person via WebRTC, is it possible to subtract the background and replace it with a custom background?.

The idea is to capture movement as it says here: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/javascript-motion-detection.html , the problem is that when there are very strong lights in the background, this also is processed altering the final product

Answer (score -3):

Background of a video element can be customized using [chrome's alpha transparency feature](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2013/07/Alpha-transparency-in-Chrome-video). A demo by Sam: http://simpl.info/videoalpha/

Comment: This requires the video input itself to come with transparency data, video recorded from webcams only come with solid pixels, and just putting a background-color or placing an element behind the video container does not remove the background from the video